# Android DatePicker showing Full Screen on Initialization

Tags: java, android, xml, dialog, datepicker

I have followed [this tutorial](http://pavanhd.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-datepicker-dialog-example.html) to integrate a datepicker into my app, I have tailored the original to suit my needs and managed to get it working. Unfortunately the author doesn't go too much into the concepts of actually using the DatePicker dialog.

As a result, a full screen calendar is shown when the app is launched, whereas I am simply trying to pull the day, month and year when the button 'Pick Date' is clicked, what do I need to remove?

Code here:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnCheckedChangeListener {

    TabHost th;

    Button  changeDate;


    TextView displayDate;
    public static final int dDialogId = 1;
    // date and time
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Set activity to full screen!!
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        th = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);

        th.setup();
        TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
        // one tab
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        // what appears on actual tab
        specs.setIndicator("Tools");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
        // one tab
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        // what appears on actual tab
        specs.setIndicator("Calorie Calculator");
        th.addTab(specs);
        specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
        // one tab
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        // what appears on actual tab
        specs.setIndicator("Your Stats!");
        th.addTab(specs);

        initializeVariables();
}


    private void initializeVariables() {

        mapARun = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMapARun);
        weightConverter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWeightConverter);

        changeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);
        displayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplayDate);

        changeDate.setOnClickListener(this);

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        updateDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    @Deprecated
    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog);

        ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);

    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };

    private void updateDisplay() {
        displayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mDay).append("-")
                .append(mYear));

    }



        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnChangeDate:
            DatePickerDialog DPD = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            DPD.show();
            break;

        }

    }



    }

}
```

Apologies if you hit syntax errors when the codei s run, I cut out a lot of the other, unrelated functions,

Is there another way to just show the datepicker when the *dialog* is called?

Answer (score 0):

Create yout main category with just the button.
Make the button call another activity with your code.
You'll get a screen with a button that calls another screen with a fullscreen datepicker.

Make the DatePicker Activity end itself when date is selected.
Make sure you are calling the activity with startActivityForResult and end it with finishWithResult.

Comment: is there no way to just set the button to call the 'mini' date picker when its selected, the way the app is setup i don't really want to invoke a whole seperate activity just for setting a date